# Unable to align div to right side Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to get my interface working

```html
            <div class="tier" id="t1">
                <div class='title'>
                    <h3>Tier 1</h3>
                    <h3 class="price">$5</h3>
                </div>
                <div class='description'>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Soundboard Access</li>
                        <li>In-Game and Discord tag</li>
                        <li>VIP and Donator channel access</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tier" id="t2">
                <div class='title'>
                    <h3>Tier 2</h3>
                    <h3 class="price">$8</h3>
                </div>
                <div class='description'>
                    <ul>
                        <li><span>All Previous Perks</span></li>
                        <li>Create a poll once per week</li>
                        <li>Choose SCP of the Day once per week</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

```css
.tier {
  border: 1px solid #007eff;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
}

.title {
  margin-top: -10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.price {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-bottom: -3px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.description {
  margin: 3px;
  text-align: end;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

This is so far what I have, and for the most part it works, but I am struggling to get `.description` to align to the right.
I read the [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container#aligning_one_item_with_align-self) and I am supposed to be able to use align-self to move it to the end of the div, but that doesn't work. (does absolutely nothing)

Here is what it looks like right now:
[image]

Here is somewhat how I'd like it to look:
[image]

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply `justify-content:space-between` to `.tier`.

[As per MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content):

> The items are evenly distributed within the alignment container along the main axis. The spacing between each pair of adjacent items is the same. The first item is flush with the main-start edge, and the last item is flush with the main-end edge.

```css
.tier {
  border: 1px solid #007eff;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.title {
  margin-top: -10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.price {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-bottom: -3px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.description {
  margin: 3px;
  text-align: end;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="tier" id="t1">
  <div class='title'>
    <h3>Tier 1</h3>
    <h3 class="price">$5</h3>
  </div>
  <div class='description'>
    <ul>
      <li>Soundboard Access</li>
      <li>In-Game and Discord tag</li>
      <li>VIP and Donator channel access</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tier" id="t2">
  <div class='title'>
    <h3>Tier 2</h3>
    <h3 class="price">$8</h3>
  </div>
  <div class='description'>
    <ul>
      <li><span>All Previous Perks</span></li>
      <li>Create a poll once per week</li>
      <li>Choose SCP of the Day once per week</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this reply, it worked perfectly. I will accept it as an answer as soon as I can.